# angular 6 universal issue 'Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './dist/server/main' in '/var/www/html/angular6/testing''

Tags: angular6

I am trying to do universal rendering in angular 6 with the help of [this link](https://angular.io/guide/universal#build).I followed the steps mentioned in the above link,but it shows following error.

```
ERROR in ./server.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './dist/server/main' in '/var/www/html/angular6/testing'
 @ ./server.ts 16:9-38
```

**server.ts**

```
// These are important and needed before anything else
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3005;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main');

// Express Engine
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
// Import module map for lazy loading
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

// TODO: implement data requests securely
app.get('/api/*', (req, res) => {
  res.status(404).send('data requests are not supported');
});

// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

can anyone please help me to solve this issue?I already spend lot of time in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There were a number of breaking changes and the documentation isn't up to date.

Step 3 of https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering fixed the issue you mentioned for me.

I had been using the nx workspace generator and it was serving up the server into the browser rather than building the files in angular.json as outlined below:

```
"architect": {
   "build": { ... }
   "server": {
     "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
     "options": {
       "outputPath": "dist/your-project-name-server",
       "main": "src/main.server.ts",
       "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
     }
   }
}
```